# Very slow cursor SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, while-loop, cursor

I don't know why this is so slow

```
DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT mediatime, ShortDate, MediaDateID, TimeID 
    FROM DateTimeMCross

DECLARE @mediatime INT, @ShortDate DATE, @MediaDateID INT, @TimeID INT, @tmpDate DATE

SET @mediatime = 0;

OPEN kursor

FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @mediatime, @ShortDate, @MediaDateID, @TimeID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    /*SET @tmpDate = (select DATEADD(day,-1,@shortDate))*/
    IF @mediatime >= 2400
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DateTimeMCross
        SET DateTimeMCross.newMediaDateID = 2/*(SELECT     YEAR(@tmpDate) * 10000 + MONTH(@tmpDate) * 100 + DAY(@tmpDate))*/
        WHERE DateTimeMCross.MediaDateID = @MediaDateID 
          AND DateTimeMCross.TimeID = @TimeID
    END
    ELSE IF @mediatime < 2400 AND @mediatime >= 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DateTimeMCross
        SET DateTimeMCross.newMediaDateID = @MediaDateID
        WHERE DateTimeMCross.MediaDateID = @MediaDateID 
          AND DateTimeMCross.TimeID = @TimeID
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @mediatime, @ShortDate, @MediaDateID, @TimeID
END

CLOSE kursor
DEALLOCATE kursor
```

I make before one statement with cursor and it was fast and this is really really slow.

I thought at the beginning it was caused by `DATEADD()` and other function but no. After comment out it is as slow as before

Comment: Is "it's slow because it's a cursor" an acceptable answer? Not being flippant, but this could easily be a set based operation and the performance would be light years faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This reaaaaaally doesn't need to be a cursor at all. Seems like you want a simple `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE DateTimeMCross
SET newMediaDateID = CASE 
                        WHEN mediatime >= 2400 THEN 2
                        ELSE MediaDateID
                     END
;
```

Comment: He may have `mediatime < 0` or `mediatime` could be a nullable field, so the `ELSE` seems iffy to me.

Comment: O god. Sorry for my foolishness. I just started my fairytail with sql but this ... :D I was trying 2 hours to make that

Comment: The `CASE` needs to handle the condition when `mediatime <2400 AND mediatime >=0`

Answer (score 1):

You just need an `UPDATE`, not a cursor:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.newMediaDateID = CASE 
                        WHEN mediatime>=2400 THEN 2 
                        WHEN mediatime <2400 AND mediatime >=0 THEN MediaDateID
                        END
FROM DateTimeMCross d
```